# Use terminal in Mac for file transfer

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, file-transfer

I am using terminal in Mac for SSH access and it is great. But is there any way for me to do file transfer with the remote server that I SSH into in Mac?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scp is your friend, enough said :)

Answer (score 0):

(I realize this is a late reply, but I just stumbled upon this question and thought I'd contribute a tip...)

A quick & dirty way of transferring files over Terminal is:

**On the remote side:**

```
cat $file | openssl enc -base64
```

This will output a bunch of uppercase/lowercase/digits which represent Base64-encoded binary data. Select & copy this block text.

Then, in a separate Terminal window **on your local machine**:

```
pbpaste | openssl enc -base64 -d > $file
```

This will pipe the contents of the clipboard (the Base64-encoded data) to the `openssl` program (which is set to decode via the `-d` flag), and save the results in `$file`.

This works best for small files, and isn't terribly fast. I use it when I'm too lazy to construct a command line for `scp` or `sftp`. For larger/multiple files, you'll definitely want to use the latter two.